# Jira-Python - Specify API version?

Tags: python, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Using Jira-Python, how do you specify the API versioning that the `issues=` command sends? i.e.,

```
https:///rest/api/2/search?
```

vs.

```
/api/latest/search ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tony, the version is hardcoded into the imported library. If I were looking for the API call I would use a breakpoint in your script, debug it and step into the methods to find where the version is defined.
Hope this helps.